# QString::fromStdString returns broken text

Tags: qt

In my Qt GUI app I use libwebrtc. From one on callbacks I want to emit signal with data, which is std::string. As core app logic use QString, I want convert std::string to Qstring.
I try following:

```
QString::fromStdString(stdstr)
QString::fromLatin1(stdstr.data())
```

Both of this return broken text, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXmbs.png)

Only working way for me was

```
QString qstr;
for(uint i =0; i< stdstr.length(); i++)
    qstr.append(stdstr.at(i));
```

Here my thoughts about reason of problem:

1. Encoding problems.
2. Binary problems

About encoding, libwebrtc *should* return std::string in UTF-8 by default, same as QString.

About binary. As I understand Qt built with GCC and corresponding stdlib, but libwebrtc build with CLang and libc++. For building I also specify usinng `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++`

What is correct way to convert types here?

**UPD**

I compare length of converted string and source string, they are very different.

For std::string I get 64, and for converted QString I get 5.

**UPD2**

Here is  full function and corresponding slot for SPDGen signal

```
void foo(const webrtc::IceCandidateInterface *candidate) override {
    std::string str;
    candidate->ToString(&str);
    QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(str);
    qDebug() << qstr;
    Q_EMIT SPDGen(qstr);
}

connect(conductor, &Conductor::SPDGen, this, [=](QString value){
    ui->textEdit->setText(value);
});
```

Comment: It might be an encoding issue. Did you try something like: `QString::fromUtf8(stdstr.data());`?

Comment: @vahancho  Yes, I try also `QString::fromUtf8`, `QString::fromLatin1`, `QString::fromLocal8Bit`. They return incorrect data too.

Comment: What's the content of your `stdstr`? Can you bring an example?

Comment: @vahancho 
here is how i get data for this string
`
void foo(const webrtc::IceCandidateInterface *candidate) override {
    std::string str;
    candidate->ToString(&str);
          ...
}
`
And here is actual data in contains: `candidate:3800372419 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.126.9 46851 typ ho`

Comment: Please show the complete code that is in your `foo()` function. BTW, your string looks ok, and I even don't see any of non ASCII characters.

Comment: @vahancho I update question with example code